# Redirect with PHP on Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect

I have a form which is being submitted through an AJAX call, which is sending to a PHP file called `function.php`. This is what my AJAX call looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    type:  'post',
    cache:  false ,
    url:  'function.php',
    data: noteSequence,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);

        <?php
            if (defined('RESTRICTED')) {
                if (!isset($_SESSION['logged'])) {
                    header( 'Location: index.php' );
                    exit();
                }
             }
        ?>
    }
});
```

On the PHP file I have this if statement. If this is true I want the page to redirect to `index.php`. A `header()` isn't working. I tried `window.location.href = 'index.php';` after the AJAX has been successful, but this is redirecting regardless if the PHP statement is true or not. Currently I was trying to use sessions to redirect the user but thats not working. So can anyone offer a solution please?

PHP code:

```
if ($rows == 1) { 
    $_SESSION['logged'];
}
```

Comment: You can set flag in your `function.php` for your `if ( !isset( $_SESSION['logged'] ) )` condition and return it. If flag is true then redirect user using `location.replace('index.php')`.

Comment: Or I could possibly paste this into another php file and require it ?

Comment: No not necessary. Just check login status in your  `function.php` and pass result to ajax.

Comment: Please check answer I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function.php perform your actions and then add below lines at the end where you send response

```
$login_status = false;
if (defined('RESTRICTED')) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['logged'])) {
        $login_status = true;
    }
}

$response = array();
$response['login_status'] = $login_status;

echo json_encode($response);
```

In your JS code:

```
$.ajax({
    type:  'post',
    cache:  false ,
    url:  'function.php',
    data: noteSequence,
    success: function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        if(data['login_status']) {
            location.replace("index.php")
        } else {
            //do something else
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response appreciate it. No luck unfortunately 
if ($rows == 1) { 

$_SESSION['logged'];
}




if (defined('RESTRICTED')) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['logged'])) {
        $login_status = true;
    }
}

$response = array();
$response['login_status'] = $login_status;

echo json_encode($response);

Comment: My PHP is doing its job thats brilliant i'm getting this : {"login_status":true}  I think its a problem with my if statement on ajax ?

Comment: Is `success: function(data)` returning ` {"login_status":true}`?

Comment: I'm alert(data); after success that is what i'm getting?

Comment: try this: `data = JSON.parse(data); alert(data['login_status']);` Just before it `console.log(data)`. see exact format of data you are getting

Comment: Ah getting true on that

Comment: @Ryan if it works for just accept the answer so that future readers can get answer

Answer (score 0):

If you expect browser redirect, header won't affect the browser state for ajax calls and browser won't navigate the address on header. Instead header you should use client side methods to redirect browser like below,

```
$.ajax({
    type:  'post',
    cache:  false ,
    url:  'function.php',
    data: noteSequence,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.notloggedin)
            window.location.href = data.href;
        else
            //Your business
    }
});
```

Edit: You should return your data properly for ajax call in my example code need a href property in json result. Your should edit the behaviour of ajax result which related with "data"

The php code you need to have something like below for function.php But please mind you should parameterize your request for function.php otherwise that will function for just checking session of user.

```
<?PHP

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$myAjaxResult = array();
$myAjaxResult["notLoggedIn"] = true;
if (defined('RESTRICTED')) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['logged'])) {
        $myAjaxResult["notLoggedIn"] = true;
    }
    else {
        $myAjaxResult["notLoggedIn"] = false;
    }
}
echo json_encode($myAjaxResult);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Slighlty confused how I would set this up but I know what you mean. So in my php file I could have $redirect = true , then in my ajax if $redirect = true redirect ?

Comment: Not exactly like that I modified my answer for your situation. But please mind that thats not the whole answer of your business, just the checking and redirecting part of your business.